# Substract neighbours from matrix

Tags: matlab

OK, so I suspect that this might be rather easy, but cannot find any good help online except for bits and pieces.

I have a NxN-matrix that I want to do sort of an edge detect for. I want to substract a factor of all neighbouring values, if they exist.

So if my matrix consists of `[5, 5, 5 ; 5, 10, 5 ; 5, 5, 5]` I want it to return `[4, 3, 4 ; 3, 8, 3 ; 4, 3, 4]` (incredibly rough estimate just to give an example).

I can see how it would be done with for-loops, but I'm thinking it may be doable in an easier and less taxing way. So far, nlfilter seems to be a possible way out, but I cannot seem to figure it out completely on my own.

Comment: How did you arrive at those results? What were the mathematical operations? Are you considering 8 neighbors or 4?

Comment: Those results were simply made by creating a 3x3 matrix in which a factor of pos 2,4,6,8 were substracted from pos 5. Does that help? @beaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mathematical operation you're describing is called [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).

Convolution basically amounts to replacing every pixel in an image with a weighted sum of itself and its neighbours. The weights are given in a (usually small) matrix called a *kernel*, or sometimes *impulse response*.

For edge detection I recommend either the [Sobel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) or [discrete Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator#Image_Processing) kernels.

The MATLAB function [`conv2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) can do the image convolution for you.

```
kernel = [ 0  1  0
           1 -4  1
           0  1  0 ];
edges = conv2(image,kernel,'same');
```

Comment: Nice. +1 for Sobel and Laplacian. I probably should have mentioned them.

Comment: Thank you!
I will be trying out this solution; am I right in fearing that the other solution (using filter2d) may use already weighted numbers (same matrix) to calculate any value after the first?

Comment: This function returns a N+2*N+2 matrix though. Any way to fix this (apart from creating a new matrix without those columns&rows)?

Comment: @ades I just fixed that problem now--you need to add the `'same'` parameter to the function call. From what I can tell, `filter2d` and `conv2` are being used in pretty much the same way here. My `kernel` is beaker's `h`. I think the only difference is that `conv2` will flip the `kernel` matrix left-right and then up-down. But this won't matter if the kernel is symmetric.

Comment: Ah thanks man, runs a charm now @eigenchris. Is there any real difference between your solution and that of @beaker?

Comment: @ades They are the exact same, but only because the kernels are symmetric. Try `conv2` and `filter2` with the matrix `[1 2 1; 0 0 0; -1 -2 -1];` on any image. The results will be mirrored. You'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for something like [filter2(h,X)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter2.html)

Given your example, `h` would be something like

```
h = [  0  -0.1   0;
     -0.1   1  -0.1;
       0  -0.1   0];
```

This takes the value at the center and subtracts 1/10 of each of its 4 neighbors. If you use `filter2(h,X,'same')`, where X is your original matrix, it will pad with zeros, which appears to be what you want to get the edge values right.

Comment: `'same'` is definitely a nice feature to use. I even didn't know `filter2d` existed.

Comment: @eigenchris Yes, it just depends on whether you've padded your array yourself or not. In this case I'm assuming not. :)

Comment: @eigenchris But you want to be careful using `filter2d`. It's actually the cross correlation, which rotates the kernel 180 degrees. It doesn't matter if your kernel is symmetrical, but if it's not it can drive you crazy trying to debug it.

Comment: At the risk of being confusing, I think convolution is technically the one that involves the kernel-flipping and cross-correlation is the one that keeps it the same? It either case, good thing to point out. I tend to forget it even happens because most image filters are symmetric as you said.

Comment: @eigenchris You are right. Here's the part that was confusing me from the help page, "Two-dimensional correlation is equivalent to two-dimensional convolution with the filter matrix rotated 180 degrees." What that really means is that cross correlation is the equivalent of **not** rotating the kernel at all rather than rotating it twice ;)

Comment: Well I would say that's a pretty ... *convoluted* ... way of explaining things. But yeah, it's not as if it's that big a deal 90% of the time. Just me being picky with vocabulary. :)

Comment: Thanks @beaker!
Since the operation is made on my matrix, will already weighted numbers be used when calculating values after the first? I.e. that the 2nd position uses the already processed 1st position value rather than the original 1st position value.

Comment: With this function, I get error messages due to filter2d undefined for input of double type (even when I change the kernel to integer values).

Comment: @ades My apologies. In addition to getting confused between convolution and cross correlation, I also seem to have typed the name of the method incorrectly. It's `filter2`, without the `d`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Tried your solution even though the other answer worked, and it seems to work equally well @beaker :)

Comment: `filter2` ignores new values in its calculations. It essentially creates a new output matrix and leaves the input matrix unchanged, using only the original values throughout the calculation. You might also be interested in looking at `imfilter` and `fspecial` for even more options. :)